# ASP.Net membership validating users created manually

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider

I am manually creating users in my asp.net user tables with the membership.creatuser().  Is there an easy way to test to make sure the account is created and or valid after I create it?

```
MembershipCreateStatus status = new MembershipCreateStatus();
Membership.CreateUser(user.FirstName + user.LastName, 
                       user.Password, user.Email);
```

I would basically like to do an auto sign in to the site and then return if it was successful or not?

Any links or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `CreateUser()` method has an `out` parameter that will return a `MembershipCreateStatus` `enum` with details about what happened.  Anything other than `Success` from that `enum` indicates a potential problem.

I see you've declared your `status` variable, you just need to use it!